# How to replace IN clause with JOIN clause in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written SQL with IN clause but I have tried writing the same with JOIN but with no luck.

```
select MSG.ID
from AOUT MSG, AOUTMSG OUTM
where OUTM.ID = MSG.ID
and MSG.ID  in (
  select ID
  from AOUTID MSGID1
  where MSGID1.ID = MSG.ID
  and trim(MSGID1.TYPEFLG) = 'DEMO'

  )
and MSG.ID in (
  select ID
  from AOUTID  MSGID2
  where MSGID2.ID = MSG.ID
  and trim(MSGID2.MKT_ID_TYPE_FLG) = 'KEEP'

  )
```

Comment: `but I have tried writing the same with JOIN but with no luck` ← Can you please also post that? Show us your attempt.

Comment: `from AOUT MSG, AOUTMSG OUTM where OUTM.ID = MSG.ID` ← you can start by moving the join syntax to the `from` clause instead of having it in the `where` clause. Once you get that you can expand it and convert your IN statement to also be in the FROM clause.

Comment: What is this query supposed to do? It makes little sense to join `AOUTMSG` when you don't use it, except that you'll get more duplicates, and exclude results for which there is no matching record in that table.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `join`.  Just use aggregation and `having`:

```
select aout.id
from aout
group by aout.id
having sum(case when trim(aout.TYPEFLG) = 'DEMO' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when trim(MSGID3.MKT_ID_TYPE_FLG) = 'KEEP' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Comment: Appreciate but how shall I change the query if i need to use Join only?

Comment: @tulumatinee . . . `JOIN` isn't needed.  You can return the correct result set using just one table reference.

Comment: `AOUTMSG` may limit result set, so the join with it *may be* required

Comment: Sorry, i have to update my question. In my earlier question I used same table name in main and sub query, with the latest change sub query has different table.